# Do we still need Newtonian G in General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, newtonian-gravity

I believe we can use [Newtonian Physics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_mechanics) to make incredibly good predictions about the movement of celestial bodies as long as they are not too fast/massive and there are only two of them (well, we can make predictions for more bodies, but not the general case, right?)

And I think the only number we need in order to make predictions, besides the positions/speeds/masses of the bodies, is $G$ (i.e. [Newton's gravitational constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation)), and all the math we need is what we call [calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus).

But we can make even better predictions if we use [General Relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity), and some mathematical objects called tensors, and the speed of light $c$, right? Or do we still need $G$ in GR?

Comment: The answer is yes; we still need $G$. More information can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations

Comment: G is a constant in Einstein's field equations, as @Hunter linked to.

Comment: Because it pops up regularly in GR, it's often taken to be 1 to make writing equations more simple (see [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units#Geometrized_units) for more info).

Comment: > _well, we can make predictions for more bodies, but not the general case, right?_ Classical N-body problem has been solved analytically by Q. Wang, who generalized solution of 3-body problem by Sundman. Although these solutions are useless practically because of very slow convergence of the series, N-body problems still can be (and are) treated numerically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

G is required in the equations, though usually we choose a unit system where it is set to one for convenience.

In the GR field equations  it usually appears on the side with the stress-energy tensor, along with some dimensionless constant.

One way to look at it is that we still need a fundamental constant to relate the three units of mass, length, and time. We cannot write a meaningful expression with mass on one side (unless it is in a ratio, which it isn't) without a fundamental constant capable of getting rid of the mass unit. The metric generated (an expression without mass units) is dependant on the energy distribution (an expression with mass units), so G must pop in somewhere. Of course, it could be a different constant like $\hbar$ , but G makes the most sense intutively and is indeed the actual constant found in the equations.

Besides, GR should limit to newtonian gravity in the classical limit, so some form of G ought to be present.

Comment: > _some form of G ought to be present_ I think OP means that it might have reduced into a combination of something more fundamental.

Comment: I had the illusion, based on my ignorance, that c would have been enough. So sad.

Comment: @PabloGrisafi: there's no way of getting around needing some sort of conversion factor for "how much gravity is generated by X amount of mass", in the roughest sense.